# Php move cursor to last line

Tags: php, joomla

I am using a module in joomla called blank module which unfortunately does not come with much documentation. It allows you to specify HTML code and php. However the php output is always on a new line.

Is there any way in php where you can move the cursor back to the previous line before echoing output.

Current Behaviour

```
HTML OUTPUT

PHP OUTPUT
```

Desired Behaviour:

```
HTML OUTPUT PHP OUTPUT
```

by coding in moving to previous line in php.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6939763/2675154) answer on Stack Overflow is of some help.

Comment: Hi Honk. that does not seem to help. The best I have got is adding the ASCII backspace character chr(8) but that does not take me to the previous line. Thought would be simple but obviously not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did not find a solution with PHP but assigned a css tag to the second output and used:

```
position: relative;
```

tag to move the output!

A bit of a cheat but got the required results!

This can the first bit of documentation for Joomla blank module.